# Chromium in headless mode is not getting media stream from webcam

Tags: chromium, headless-browser

I was trying to test if Chromium on Linux is accessing the webcam correctly via the headless mode:

```
chromium-browser --headless https://example.com --repl
```

But chrome seemed to be ignoring video capturing device input, since the the webcam indicator LED was not lighting up. However, the same test page worked just fine when Chrome was running in GUI mode.

Here is the output prompt before the *REPL* line:

> [0512/233001.068247:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1019)] Lost UI shared context.
>
> [0512/233002.458966:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(102)] Not implemented reached in std::list media::(anonymous namespace)::GetFrameRateList(int, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)
>
> [0512/233002.459566:INFO:headless_shell.cc(399)] Type a Javascript expression to evaluate or "quit" to exit.

Is this a limitation of the headless mode of Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use webcam? If not, then you can use fake cam?

If so, then try:

```
chrome.exe --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --disable-web-security --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture="C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\fileName.y4m" --allow-file-access
```

Using this way you can test webcam in chrome.

Comment: Thank you for the information! The project from which the original question arose was passed on to other teams. I will forward your solution to them.